# Golang, calling a new system call in Linux

Tags: linux, go

I have a Linux kernel with a custom system call. In C, I can use the standard C library syscall() to call a system call by its number. How can I call this new system call in Go?

In C, on Linux, there are also macros that can emit the needed inline assembly to make a system call directly.

I would hate to have to hack syscall_linux.go.

I see that in Go, syscall_linux.go is processed by a perl script (mysyscall.pl) to generate assembly. That is also pretty complicated and hacking it to generate a new stub also seems needlessly messy.

Answer (score 6):

The [`syscall`](http://golang.org/pkg/syscall/) package has `syscall.Syscall` and `syscall.Syscall6` to make syscalls directly.

Comment: Those are not quite enough. It appears syscall.Syscall is for 3 arg systems calls. C has macros of zero, one, two, etc so I guess they could have made a whole set but I don't see it. My custom system call has one parameter, an int32, btw.

Here is an example I found of Go code using syscall.Syscall syscall.Syscall(syscall.SYS_IOCTL, fd, cmd, ptr)

Comment: What have you tried? Not every syscall has 3 or 6 parameters, just use what you need like in the syscall package. (e.g. Lstat has 2 params and works with Syscall or Syscall6 :http://play.golang.org/p/S_BP1vf6xX)

Comment: That is great. Yes, none have more than 6 so just passing 0, say, for the unused args should work. Thanks a lot.